# Reading XML with VB.Net

Tags: xml, vb.net

I am trying to parse out an xml doc in vb.net. I can almost get what I need but the fields I am trying to pull data from are like so -

```
<field name="name_first">
   <data>Todd</data>
</field>
<field name="name_last">
   <data>Smith</data>
</field>
```

I am able to loop through and by doing this -

```
For Each innerNode1 as XmlNode in ourerNode1.ChildNodes 
   For Each innerNode2 in innerNode1.ChildNodes 
      fldName = innerNode2.Name 
      Location = innerNode2.InnerText 
   Next 
Next
```

I get field for fieldName and Todd for Value. Is there a way I can set

fieldName = ? so I can get the name of the field so instead of getting back field I would get name_first?

Much appreciated!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? I can't really understand the specifics of your question. Seeing your code might help.

Comment: To help you, as @MattJones is saying, we'll need a [minimal code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to work with.  There is a great number of ways (and libraries) to work with XML.

Comment: <field name="name_first">
<data>Todd</data>
</field>

Data above is what I trying to read. I need to get the field na,e value of name_first. Below is a code snippet
For Each innerNode1 as XmlNode in ourerNode1.ChildNodes
For Each innerNode2 in innerNode1.ChildNodes
fldName = innerNode2.Name
Location = innerNode2.InnerText
Next
Next                                                                                                                      I am getting the value of "field" for fldName above What I want to get is "name_first".

Comment: "name_first" is the value of the name `attribute`. XmlNodes have an Attributes collection that will contain the value. You can also get the value using xpath.